# Why Warning about Apt's partner in this /etc/apt/sources.list of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 16.04

I use the default GUI to select the packages but it complicates in the package of `partner` in
`/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted


# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted contrib non-free
# deb-src http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted contrib non-free
# deb-src http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

I do `sudo apt-get update`

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Fetched 94.5 kB in 0s (200 kB/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
```

It says line 46 i.e. `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner` but I do not see anything wrong in it. It may be that `partner` includes something that the first .deb line.

### Error happens when

I had in Software sources

[image]

Now, and no such a warning

[image]

Note there are the same field two times for some reason. 
Here, we want to understand why such a warning comes or why there are two such fields.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list` file and be done with the errors.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list
```

This is where your double entry errors originate from, you have the two lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file enabled and up to that the lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list`.

For a further clue where that file comes from as you asked in comments you might want to have a look at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/294476

Comment: Why? I do not want fix things by removals. I think I need the package.

Comment: they contain the same lines, so either you comment the lines in one of the files or you live with those error messages :) One of them is redundant. So why keep a file which simply contains stuff which is aslready in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I cannot trust that Ubuntu makes duplicate package things for `partner`. It does not make sense. They may contain some duplicate lines but not all.

Comment: I just tried to change around settings from GUI side but even that did not cause this file to appear, I really have no clue where you get that file from, but I'm sure it only contains the two lines which are already in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: The file is given by Ubuntu with GUI manipulations. Ubuntu inserted the line there itself. Yes, that is a good point. I really want to understand too why Ubuntu puts me such a partner line in `sources.list`.

Comment: Recheck my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason why that line is there, it's source code rather than day to day applications that average people use.

[image]

The reason why there are 2 entries is one of them is source and the other is built applications.

[image]

In regards to the other answer, I would suggest leaving them there and not removing. If it's not broken don't fix it!

Comment: Ok, I have modified my answer to fit the question. Sorry, I misunderstood! :)